# Sistema de notificações, _.template(...).html is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js

Estou fazendo um sistema de notificações e estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _.template(...).html is not a function
```

Segue aqui o código:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="notifications-template">
    <ul>
        <%
        _.each(notifications, function(notification{
        if( notification.type == 1){ %>
        <li><% = notification.gig.artist.name %>has canceled the gig at <% = notifications.gig.venue at <% =notifications.gig.datetime. %></li>
            <%
        }

        }))
        %>

    </ul>

</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/api/notifications", function (notifications) {
            $(".js-notifications-count")
            .text(notifications.length)
            .removeClass("hide")
            .addClass("animated bounceInDown");

            $(".notifications").popover({
                html: true,
                title: "Notifications",
                content: function () {
                    var compiled = _.template("#notifications-template").html();
                    return compiled({ notifications: notifications });
                },
                placement: "bottom"
            });

        });


    });

</script>
```

## Atualização

Estava faltando o '$' seletor dentro de `_.template($("#notificação").html()`

Porém agora recebo um erro no *underscore.js*

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Comment: A função `_.template` existe? Esse `.html()` no final faz parte dela? Tenta tirar o .html()

Comment: '#notification-template' Isso está aparecendo lá nas notificações, sendo que era para aparecer as notificações, e este _.template é de uma biblioteca o _"underscore.js"_

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações, pois costumamos mantê-las o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat do Stack Overflow em Português](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) :)

Comment: Faltou fechar o novo parentese que você abriu

Comment: Não foi bem assim, estou tentando a um tempo, porém está dando n.replace is not a function, já reinstalei a biblioteca e nada

Comment: Quando você incluiu o símbolo do seletor ($), você fechou o parênteses do método template? `_.template($("#notificação").html());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sintaxe de ambas bibliotecas estão incorretas:

De acordo com a documentação do [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

Você precisa enviar um elemento HTML como parametro para _.template();

Por Exemplo:

```
var template = _.template("<b><%- value %></b>");
```

e selecionar um elemento do HTML via jQuery utilizando:

[função .html() jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$("#notifications-template").html()
```

E no seu caso você colocou:

```
_.template("#notifications-template").html();
```

O certo seria colocar:

```
_.template($("#notifications-template").html());
```

E caso o elemento de id `notifications-template` exista ele irá te retornar o HTML.

No início da `<ul>` temos alguns erros de sintaxe nos fechamentos das funcoes e nos interpolate `<% %> <%= %> <%- %>`, tente utilizar este código:

```
<ul>
    <%
        _.each(notifications, function (notification){
            if(notification.type == 1){ 
                <li><%= notification.gig.artist.name %> has canceled the gig at <%= notifications.gig.venue at%> <%=notifications.gig.datetime.%></li>
            }
        });
    %>
</ul>
```

Para entender mais sobre como usar o template veja estes exemplos:

[Exemplo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/aPv9H/626/)

[Exemplo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/bnSmh/)

[Exemplo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/23uTD/1/)

E também temos esta pergunta no stack overflow em inglês que é bem útil, foi de onde eu tirei as fontes do jsfiddle: [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778881/how-to-use-underscore-js-as-a-template-engine)

Acredito que acima temos tudo o que você precisa para resolver seu problema, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara, não foi, eu vi isso, verifiquei realmente isso no mesmo dia, mas agora estou tendo 'underscore-min.js:formatted:969Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {(…)' lá na própria biblioteca underscore.js , não sei mais o que fazer :( já regredi a versão, já fiz o diabo a 4 e não adiantou

Comment: O que você tem na sua variável notifications? Você tem certeza que você deve passar a variável inteira dentro do: compiled({ notifications: notifications });? Acredito que você deve incluir somente um atributo desta  variável, porque você vai retornar um template em HTML no _.template e aplicar em algum atributo que esta dentro de notifications.

Comment: Sim, está correto, como pode ver para cada item dentro de notifications ele vai criar aquele item lá em cima, estou achando que é a sintaxe lá em cima que esta errada, você poderia me ajudar? onde diz: `.each(notifications, function(notification{
            if( notification.type == 1){ %>
            <li><% = notification.gig.artist.name %>has canceled the gig at <% = notifications.gig.venue at <% =notifications.gig.datetime. %></li>
                <%
            }` Acho que não é bem assim e não estou encontrando ajuda

Comment: Editei o post, dê uma checada.